# An Error occurred delivering to the app store

Tags: ios, flutter, proxy

I am trying to release my project to the app store. However I get this error:

'An Error occurred delivering to the app store.'

First I tried to release it directly from Xcode. Following the advice I found on here, I then tried it using Transporter. The same error occurred but I got an extended delivery log:

> [2019-10-29 14:04:49 WITA]   INFO: An error occurred checking the HEAD for: https://contentdelivery.itunes.apple.com/transporter/repositories/j2se8/latest/repository.xml Unable to tunnel through proxy. Proxy returns "HTTP/1.1 502 Bad Gateway" Exception's name: java.io.IOException, Exception's message: Unable to tunnel through proxy. Proxy returns "HTTP/1.1 502 Bad Gateway"

Can someone help me fix this or point me in the right direction please, as I'm pretty lost with it.

Many thanks

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Try following

Go to Preferences > Network > Advanced > Proxies and make sure "Auto Proxy Discovery" and "Automatic Proxy Configuration" are checked but none of the other proxy options are checked.

[image]

Comment: Yes, it's worked for me but I just uncheck all and apply the save changes.

Comment: I have been stuck on this for the past day and a half. You saved me from going insane. Thank you!

Comment: Yes, it works. But I want to know why it works, can you explain it? Thank you very much.